# unable to run the HtmlUnit Driver with selenium Webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

This is the code :

[image]

And error :

[image]

I am trying to run the script in headless browser but it gives the error as mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: Your error is in which line../

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Also provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use phantomjs instead of HTMLUnit driver for headless automation

Now if you want to use headless with phantomjs. download the stable build of phantomjs for your headleass jobs. download it from below link :-

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Now add `System.setPropertybefore` driver instance

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); // not really needed: JS enabled by default
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:/phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

refer the link below for more info :-

http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/03/headless-browser-testing-using.html